# About a bounded net which converges in weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis

If $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence in a Hilbert space $H$ such that $||x_n|| \leq 1$ and if we have $x \in H$ such that $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$ we can prove that $||x|| \leq 1$. That because
$$||x|| \leq \liminf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}||x_n|| \leq 1$$
My question is if the same holds for nets, i.e., if I have a net $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \Lambda}$ with $||x_\alpha|| \leq 1$ for every $\alpha \in \Lambda$ and $x \in H$ such that the weak limit of $x_\alpha$ is $x$ can I prove that $||x|| \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y\in H$ with $\|y\|\leq 1$, then $\langle x, y \rangle$ is the limit of the net $\langle x_{\alpha}, y \rangle$. Since $\{\lambda \in K: |\lambda| \leq 1\}$ is closed we see that $|\langle x, y \rangle|\leq 1$. This is true whenever $y\in H$ with $\|y\|\leq 1$, so $\|x\| \leq 1$.

More general fact: Any closed convex set is weakly closed. You can apply this to the closed unit ball.

Comment: The argument of the first part seems a little confusing to me. However, the general fact helped me a lot! Thanks.

Comment: @André In the first part take $y=\frac x {\|x\|}$ to finish the proof.